# How to terminate a sudo subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, sudo, kill, tcpdump

I have a subprocess that must be started with sudo (this is an excerpt from a rather large script):

```py
            ...
            pr = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/sudo', '/usr/sbin/tcpdump', '-i', 'enp7s0',
                                   'host', adr, 'and', 'udp', 'port', '7943', '-w', fn])
            if pr.poll() is None:
                self.acquisitions.append(pr)
            ...
            for pr in self.acquisitions:
                if pr.poll() is None:
                    pr.terminate()
            self.acquisitions.clear()
            ...
```

Problem here is `pr.terminate()` fails with:

```
tcpdump: listening on enp7s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/tools/Trace.ME/App.py", line 106, in on_acquire_clicked
    pr.terminate()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1938, in terminate
    self.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1933, in send_signal
    os.kill(self.pid, sig)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

It seems `subprocess.terminate()` tries to kill directly `tcpdump` (and fails because it is owned by `root`) and not `sudo` (which is started by current user and should be killable; hitting 'CTRL-C' after `sudo tcpdump ...` works as expected).

How can I modify the code to actually stop the `tcpdump` process?

UPDATE:
As per @RossJacobs suggestion I did a further test:

```
mcon@cinderella:/tmp$ sudo tcpdump >/dev/null 2>&1 & PID=$!
[1] 1756461
mcon@cinderella:/tmp$ kill $PID
bash: kill: (1756461) - Operation not permitted
mcon@cinderella:/tmp$ fg
sudo tcpdump > /dev/null 2>&1
^Cmcon@cinderella:/tmp$ 
mcon@cinderella:/tmp$ ps ax | grep tcpdump
1758363 pts/5    S+     0:00 grep tcpdump
mcon@cinderella:/tmp$
```

It seems I cannot send a KILL signal to `sudo` even if I started it.
OTOH if I switch it to foreground I can kill it with `CTRL-C` which I *think* sends the same `TERM` signal.

What am I missing?

More to the point: is there some way to "send `CTRL-C`" to a process started with `subprocess.Popen()`?

Comment: Why not run the script like `sudo python3 script.py` and remove sudo from subprocess? Then all operations will be done by the same user.

Comment: @RossJacobs: yes, I imagine this will work. I personally dislike running things as `root` if not strictly needed; as said this is a complex GUI and things going astray would not be too "unheard of". I would like to understand why Python is unable to do something any shell is able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Per this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21272), you can't kill a process that another user created. The python process running the script has a different user than your tcpdump command, which is being run as root. You've said you're not running as sudo/root.

Many systems require sudo to inspect network traffic, which is a permission that tcpdump and wireshark/tshark require.

You can see that this is unique to unix and not to python by running these two lines. Start tcpdump with sudo in the background with `&`, and then kill it by PID with your normal user:

```sh
$ sudo tcpdump >/dev/null & PID=$!
[2] 3245434
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
$ kill $PID
-bash: kill: (3245434) - Operation not permitted
```

And you get the same error that python reports.

Comment: I do not understand. $PID refers to `sudo` process, which was started by this user (although "suid root". Anyways I *can* kill the process if it is in foreground (I will edit OP to reflect).

Comment: If you put the tcpdump command in the foreground and open another terminal tab, killing that PID will result in the same error. If the linked answer does not help you, I'm not sure what will.

Comment: Sorry being dense. I am not trying to kill `tcpdump` process that is owned by root and obviously unkillable by me. I am trying to kill the `sudo` process which *was* started by me (although it's `suid root`, of course). I *can* bring that process in foreground and kill it (killing also `tcpdump` as side effect).